# htaccess редирект / на конце

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Есть htaccess. Необходимо, чтобы при вводе site.ru/123/321/ выдавал не 404, а 301 редирект на site.ru/123/321
Так же и для всех уровней вложенности: site.ru/123/321/321/321/ на site.ru/123/321/321/321 и так далее.

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.ru
#RewriteRule (.*) http://www.site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)$ ?param1=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ ?param1=$1&param2=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ ?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ ?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&param4=$4 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ ?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&param4=$4&param5=$5 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ ?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&param4=$4&param5=$5&param6=$6 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ ?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&param4=$4&param5=$5&param6=$6&param7=$7 [QSA,L]

AddDefaultCharset utf-8
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

Comment: Позвольте спросить - а зачем оно вам?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/)$ $1 [L,R=301]
```